# Imacros: how to run a loop

Tags: loops, imacros

I have this simple one line in my imacros.

```
TAG POS=16 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
```

I want to use this line inside a loop so that value of POS is increased by 1.

So the pseudocode should look like this

```
for i = 0, i< 100; i++
 TAG POS=i TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow
```

Comment: Do you know the required amount of loops in advance? You can use {{!LOOP}} instead of a hardcoded number for your TAG POS.  With `TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow` you can then Play the Macro in Loop mode as often as you want if you know the max i in your example beforehand.

Comment: I need to loop through 100 times and max i is 100

Comment: Then you can just run it with a Max of 100 times with the Play (Loop) button and should be good to go.